# How to load all dart DateFormat locale in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization, flutter-intl

In Flutter app, intl package load only [15 languages](https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/#setting-up). However Dart [DateFormat](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) support many more. I do not need translation, but need correct `DateFormat`. How to load all `DateFormat` locale?

Comment: Do you just need the users local time or do you need a number of time zones?

Comment: I need for Date formatting.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In your highest StatefulWidget add these imports

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
```

in its State, override initState and add

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeDateFormatting();
  }
```

For example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Intl Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Intl Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateFormat dateFormat;
  DateFormat timeFormat;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeDateFormatting();
    dateFormat = new DateFormat.yMMMMd('cs');
    timeFormat = new DateFormat.Hms('cs');
  }

  void _refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var dateTime = new DateTime.now();
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(dateFormat.format(dateTime)),
            new Text(timeFormat.format(dateTime)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _refresh,
        tooltip: 'Refresh',
        child: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Dart mostly uses the [ISO 631](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) 2 letter codes, with country variants if applicable. For example: `ja, en_US, en_GB, zh_HK, zh_CN`. Occasionally it uses a 3 letter code. To find the full list just search for `DateSymbols` in the file [date_symbol_data_local.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/date_symbol_data_local.dart)

[image: The cs language displays this]

Comment: This will not work in Flutter for loading `cz` locale. Invoking `new DateFormat.yMMMMd('cz');` will cause exception in Flutter.

Comment: There isn't a cz locale. Which language are you trying to find?

Comment: I updated the answer with some examples of valid language codes and variants, and how to find the complete list. Let me know if there's a language missing.

Comment: I will test and let you known. By default Flutter package [only 15 languages](https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/#setting-up). The one I want to use in not in that list.

Comment: That's a country code, not a language code. I believe the language code for the Czech language is cs.

Comment: `initializeDateFormatting` will return a future that is complete once the locale data is available. So you should wait for it to complete before date formatting. [see DateFormat class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Comment: Flutter 2.5, I'm getting an `UnsupportedError` "Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable map" when trying to use `initializeDateFormatting()`. Anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 12):

The list of all available locales in Flutter can be take from top-level property [availableLocalesForDateFormatting](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/date_symbol_data_http_request/availableLocalesForDateFormatting.html) of `intl` package.

```dart
final availableLocalesForDateFormatting = const [
  "en_ISO",
  "af",
  "am",
  "ar",
  "ar_DZ",
  "ar_EG",
  "az",
  "be",
  "bg",
  "bn",
  "br",
  "bs",
  "ca",
  "chr",
  "cs",
  "cy",
  "da",
  "de",
  "de_AT",
  "de_CH",
  "el",
  "en",
  "en_AU",
  "en_CA",
  "en_GB",
  "en_IE",
  "en_IN",
  "en_MY",
  "en_SG",
  "en_US",
  "en_ZA",
  "es",
  "es_419",
  "es_ES",
  "es_MX",
  "es_US",
  "et",
  "eu",
  "fa",
  "fi",
  "fil",
  "fr",
  "fr_CA",
  "fr_CH",
  "ga",
  "gl",
  "gsw",
  "gu",
  "haw",
  "he",
  "hi",
  "hr",
  "hu",
  "hy",
  "id",
  "in",
  "is",
  "it",
  "it_CH",
  "iw",
  "ja",
  "ka",
  "kk",
  "km",
  "kn",
  "ko",
  "ky",
  "ln",
  "lo",
  "lt",
  "lv",
  "mk",
  "ml",
  "mn",
  "mr",
  "ms",
  "mt",
  "my",
  "nb",
  "ne",
  "nl",
  "no",
  "no_NO",
  "or",
  "pa",
  "pl",
  "ps",
  "pt",
  "pt_BR",
  "pt_PT",
  "ro",
  "ru",
  "si",
  "sk",
  "sl",
  "sq",
  "sr",
  "sr_Latn",
  "sv",
  "sw",
  "ta",
  "te",
  "th",
  "tl",
  "tr",
  "uk",
  "ur",
  "uz",
  "vi",
  "zh",
  "zh_CN",
  "zh_HK",
  "zh_TW",
  "zu"
];
```

Comment: The link is dead. Always post an answer with a description.

Answer (score 11):

I solved it setting the Intl.sytemLocale before using any DateFormat:

```
Intl.systemLocale = await findSystemLocale();
```

I didn't had to call `initializeDateFormatting()` and I'm using `intl: ^0.17.0`.

Comment: This works perfectly, just add it in main.

Comment: just don't forget to ```import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart';``` otherwise await ```findSystemLocale()``` won't work

Answer (score 11):

just add the language code like this (in my case 'ar' for Arabic)

```
  DateFormat('MMMM', 'ar')  .format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: Thanks for that. In case someone needs to find out the current locale:         DateFormat('EEEE', Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode);

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [@kapace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396202/kapace) comment:

> You should use language tag in order to be sure that you consider locale's country code. Like in Canada where language is same `en` as `en-US`, but they format dates slightly different using `en-CA` locale.

For example:

```dart
var tag = Localizations.maybeLocaleOf(context)?.toLanguageTag();

var date1 = DateFormat.yMMMd(tag).format(DateTime.now()); // Dec 31, 2000
var date2 = DateFormat('MM/dd, hh:mm a', tag).format(DateTime.now()); // 12/31, 11:00 PM
```