# Format dates with mixed locales

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to format dates according to the device's locale. If you have "standard" locales like `en_US`, `de_DE` and so on, this is no problem. But if the user has set his phone language to e.g. englisch (en) and the region to e.g. Germany (DE), the locale will be the following `en_DE` (not standard locale).

If I try now to format a date with this locale, it will always use `US` formatting (I think because auf the language part `en`):

```
String date = DateFormat.yMd('en_DE').format(DateTime.now());
print(date); // 7/13/2022
```

If I use only the region part `DE`, this will work for `DE`:

```
String date = DateFormat.yMd('DE').format(DateTime.now());
print(date); // 13.07.2022
```

But for the locale `en_US` this will not work:

```
String date = DateFormat.yMd('US').format(DateTime.now()); // Invalid argument(s): Invalid locale "US"
```

How can I format the date according to the region part of the locale?

Comment: If I understood correctly your expected output with en_DE is 13.07.2022?

Comment: Are you trying to find something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807687/how-to-load-all-dart-dateformat-locale-in-flutter

Comment: Correct @L_Cleo

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a try catch

```dart
String date = "";
String locale = 'en_US';
try{
 date = DateFormat.yMd('${locale.subString(3)}').format(DateTime.now());
}catch(e){
 date = DateFormat.yMd('$locale').format(DateTime.now());
}
print(date);
```

Comment: Not quite. If I change the locale to `en_CH` (CH = Switzerland), it tries to format the date with `CH`, which is not a valid language code so it produces an error and the catch block will be triggered. In the catch it formats the date with `en_CH` and this will format the date with `US` formatting `7/13/2022` again.

Comment: Yeah but only if ch isn't able to format it will take the us format

Comment: So it gives priority to the region. Then if it fails it takes the language

Comment: Yeah but that's not what I want. I primarily care about the region, not the language. If I set my phone's language to english and my region to switzerland, the date should be formatted like that `16.07.2022`. I need to figure out the defaults language of a region somehow.

Comment: Got it. Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807687/how-to-load-all-dart-dateformat-locale-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

for someone looking for a mixed-date format like
Arabic date format with English numbers like

```
2 أكتوبر 2023
```

maybe this will help

```
DateFormat.d('en').format(date) +
    DateFormat(' MMMM ').format(date) +
    DateFormat.y('en').format(date)
```