# How can I change the language of the intl date formater?

Tags: flutter, dart, date, date-format, intl

So I want to change the intl Date format into a french format (fr_FR). I googled and I found this line but I don't know where to put it in the code:

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
initializeDateFormatting('fr_FR', null).then((_) => runMyCode());
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/49807687/10157127 answer your quesiton

Answer (score 0):

make your widget statefull and add the line of code in the initState() method

```
@override   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeDateFormatting('fr_FR', null); }
```

package https://pub.dev/packages/intl

```
intl: ^0.17.0
```