# Flutter Intl (0.18!): Changing language for weekday

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

I want to change the language for the weekdays in intl: [image]

to German. In my code, I do this:

```
final weekdayFormatter = DateFormat('E');
final date = mostRecentWeekday(_currentDate, 1).add(Duration(days: i)); "<-- Function to get current monday"
...
 Text(weekdayFormatter.format(date)),
```

So I want Mo Di Mi Do which stands for Montag Dienstag Mittwoch [...]

I tried this function: `initializeDateFormatting();`
but I don't understand what parameters this function needs, especially the path parameter... all posts I were able to found are outdated

Comment: What answer? What Post?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807687/how-to-load-all-dart-dateformat-locale-in-flutter ... sorry, got interupted...you say posts are outdated but I doubt this area of Dart has changed much.

Comment: Seems like? Try it yourself if you don't believe me... all solutions are outdated. Nothing works for me

Comment: I believe you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by do:

```
  final weekdayFormatter = DateFormat.E('de_DE');
```

instead of:

```
final weekdayFormatter = DateFormat('E');
```

also:

```
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
```

inside Matrerial app and

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

inside pub file

and using intl 17.

Comment: Ok good. It builds with `import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart'` if you want to use `initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', null);`

Comment: ...not sure I helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try it  `initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', null);`

Add a line of code to the initState() method

Comment: dont work, using Intl 0.18 there can't be a Null value.

Comment: The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' on   @override
  `void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', null);

  }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807687/how-to-load-all-dart-dateformat-locale-in-flutter

try to watch this post, I think you will find a solution

Comment: What is the problem with switching to 0.17 or do you fundamentally want to use the latest version ?

Comment: Yeah, beacause switching to 0.17 i have to run my flutter project without sounded nullsafty

Comment: I'm happily building with full null safety with intl 0.17. It is labelled as a null safe version.

Comment: have you tried replacing null with ' '

Comment: Now I don't understand the world. Even I use intl 17 it still says string cant be null

Comment: initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', ' ');

Comment: you with '' it says: `Locale de has not been initialized. Call initializeDateFormatting(de, <data url>) first`

Comment: This package has multiple methods named `initializeDateFormatting`. If you import the one in `date_symbol_data_file.dart` then you'd hit this error. The example in the README uses `date_symbol_data_file.dart` which has an optional second argument so that looks like it could be correct.

It does look like the DateFormat documentation passes a null for all 3 examples, and likely at least 2 of those will need updates

Comment: What package shall I import? Yeah mine looks like this: `Future<void> initializeDateFormatting(String locale, String filePath) {`

Comment: `import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';`

Comment: You can see more details here:[link] https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

First in your route `MaterialApp` Widget add this parameter :

```
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
```

then use this script as language changer anywhere you need:

```
    initializeDateFormatting('de_DE');
    final weekdayFormatter = DateFormat('E', 'de_DE');
    final date = DateTime.now();
    print(weekdayFormatter.format(date)); // it will print Do
```

Comment: okay intersting since I added these things inside material I get a different error:
I also have to use: `initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', '')` because otherwise I cant compile. Anyway: new error: `Class '_Map<String, DateSymbols>' has no instance method 'initLocale'.
Receiver: _Map len:94
Tried calling: initLocale("de_DE")`

Comment: What Intl version are you using and how does your initializeDateFormatting looks inside the library ? Mine: `Future<void> initializeDateFormatting(String locale, String filePath) {`

Comment: flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0, intl 0.17.0 is required.
 this means that if you want to remain on intl 0.18 you cannot use localizations. you need to do it yourself mannually

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the right import of `initializeDateFormatting`. The easiest is to use `import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart'`, for web and for custom file loading other variants exist in `date_symbol_data_http_request.dart` and `date_symbol_data_file.dart`.